# Add margin to child of ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I created this simple example to show you the problem that I have:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{

    private final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {

        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();

        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(scroll, comboPane());
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

        stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        stackPane.setPrefSize(900, 900);

        FlowPane flowPane;

        flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        flowPane.setVgap(10);
        flowPane.setHgap(10);

        flowPane.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        flowPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        flowPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        scroll.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
        scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setContent(flowPane);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 200);

            rect.setArcHeight(15);
            rect.setArcWidth(15);

            rect.setStroke(Color.GREEN);

            flowPane.getChildren().add(rect);

        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private ComboBox<String> comboPane()
    {
        ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(options);

        return combo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see ComboBox is placed at the corner of the StackPane. I tiried to add this code combo.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

What is the proper way to add some space between the corned of the StackPane and Combobox?

Answer (score 6):

Use static methods of `StackPane`

```
ComboBox<String> cb = comboPane();
stackPane.getChildren().addAll( scroll, cb );
StackPane.setMargin( cb, new Insets( 30 ) );
```